# Onclick of menu icon tab another tab need to be display in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am developing an Ionic 2 application and have multiple tabs in my application.

- [My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L00kvQMvNWITYOc8b8QJ?p=preview) for reference.
- In bottom tab there are two tab icons are available, one is `home icon` tab another one is `menu icon` tab
- As of now when clicking the bottom tabs `menu icon`, the top tab is getting displaying  and if again clicking the button menu icon the top tab is  getting hidden this is our fuctionality.
- What I exactly looking for `on clicking the menu icon` the top tab need to be display, what is happening on here if we clicking any where on the bottom tab, the top tab gets display and hidden...

**We are looking for two tasks** :-

- First one is `on clicking the menu icon` the top tab need to be display and hidden.
- Second one is on clicking of bottom `home icon` it's need to  redirect `home page`.
- these two icons are need to perform two different actions, but here if clicking `home icon` the top tab is displaying.I don't know where i did the mistake. I am new to ionic 2 and angular 2 so please help me....
- Actually we have used this fuction `(click)="x()"` in `ion-tabs`, and also I have used this function in `ion-tab` it's not working so please check and update...I don't know where I did the mistake...

**On clicking** `tab menu Icon`:

```
    <ion-tabs tabs-only (click)="x()" >
    <ion-tab tabIcon="home" [root]="tab1Root" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="menu"  ></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**My multiple tab Elements:**

```
    <ion-tabs tabs-only (click)="x()" >
    <ion-tab tabIcon="home" [root]="tab1Root" ></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="menu"  ></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs tabs-only2 tabbar  [hidden]="hideTopTab" >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Page" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**Below function are used to [show] and [hidden] the another tab element:-**

```
    hideTopTab:boolean=true;
   x(){
     console.log(this.hideTopTab);

    this.hideTopTab = !this.hideTopTab;
}
```

Please update the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xqgvhE2R16YIO0iR0EtZ?p=preview) If you have a solution.

- Actually i am expecting exact solution as like a this link menu actions :- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav on the link if we click the menu icon the list of items are displaying and again clicking the menu button the list gets hidden...

Comment: Try replacing (click) with (ionSelect) and use it on ion-tab like this: <ion-tab (ionSelect)="x()"></ion-tab>

Comment: It's in the documentation: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tab/

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment  if you have time please update the plunker as well to know the exact solution thank you...